# Affect styles of an element if value of visible elements if greater than 0

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I am attempting to affect the styles of `#lengthTest` if the value of visible `.popParkLink` elements is greater than 0. I have been able to return the value of the number of visible `.popParkLink` however I'm struggling to affect the styles using an if statement.

Any ideas where i've gone wrong?

```
<div class="popupCustom">      
          <p class="popParkLink" style="display:none"><a href="#">test 1</a></p>
          <p class="popParkLink" style="display:block"><a href="#">test 2</a></p>
          <p id="lengthTest"></p>
</div>

var lengthTest = document.getElementById('lengthTest');
var howMany=$('.popParkLink:visible').length;

$(lengthTest).css({"color": "red"});

$(function () {     
    $(lengthTest).html(howMany); 
if(howMany > 0){(lengthTest).css({"color": "orange"});}
});
```

Comment: Use the developer console. It should have pointed you to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a $ in (lengthTest).css(..), so it's not a jQuery object you're doing the css method on.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, it's always the littlest thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {     
var lengthTest = document.getElementById('lengthTest');
var howMany=$('.popParkLink:visible').length;
$(lengthTest).css({"color": "red"});
$(lengthTest).html(howMany); 

if(parseInt(howMany) > 0){ 
   $(lengthTest).css({"color": "orange"});}
});
```